# I have to create data in this format in JS. { x: 1, y: 1, name: 'BE'},

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 3 arrays:

```
Presnt1[]={1,2,3,4,5}
Presnt2[]={1,2,3,4,5}
Presnt3[]={'Be','CR','VF','Bt','HJ'}
```

How can I create this data structure using above array in JS:-

```
{ x: 1, y: 1, name: 'BE'}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it

```
 var a,arr = [

    {"x":"value","y":"value","name":"value"},
    {"x":"value","y":"value","name":"value"}

    ];
            // arr[a]["x"]//
document.write(arr[0]["x"]) // will output value of first at row 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal works with an array for the structure of the wanted object. For each item in the structure a new property is generated and the object is then pushed to the result array.

```js
var data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    data2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    data3 = ['Be', 'CR', 'VF', 'Bt', 'HJ'];
    
function  getArray(array, structure) {
    var result = [], i = 0, o;
    while (i < array[0].length) {
        o = {};
        structure.forEach(function (k, j) {
            o[k] = array[j] && array[j][i];
        });
        result.push(o);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getArray([data1, data2, data3], ['x', 'y', 'name']), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
var pres1=[1,2,3,4,5],pres2=[1,2,3,4,5],pres3=['Be','CR','VF','Bt','HJ'];
var newArray = [];
$.each(pres1,function(i){
    newArray.push({'x':pres1[i],'y':pres2[i],'name':pres3[i]});
});
```